# Download image asynchronously

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I need to download an image from the web and display it in an `ImageView`. Presently I am using `SDWebImage` (It is an asynchronous image downloader with cache support, with a `UIImageView` category).

But it crashes when I click the back button and forward button (when I try to go back and forth of the view repeatedly). Anyway this happens very rarely, but I need to get rid of this bug. Is there any other library (that does not use private API's) that I could use in my project?

Comment: please post your crash log if possible.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. The library I suggested works perfectly. Let me know if you do not get how to implement.

Comment: If not solved yet. Use the JImage.h and JImage.m will help you out at any condition which I have posted, you just need to copy and paste that will work automatically. It's very effective classes which I have implemented and working very fine for me in lazy loading of images (async download)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. You can user other libary. I've already implemented that using **`AsyncImageView`** which is inherited from **`UIImageView`**. What it does is it stores images in Cache memory fetched from a url and whenever you need to load image from the **same** URL again it will simply load it from the cache memory saving a lot of time.

Just follow the link for implementing that:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView#readme

http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

Please have a look at the image showing the technique I've implemented. It lets you do other activity while images are loading.:

[image]

Comment: does `AsyncImageView ` or `iphone-asynchronous-table-image` use any private API ? have you come across this ?

Comment: This doesn't say if it uses private APIs or Not

Comment: Hello Rohan i used your AsyncImageView , but i face one problem , it repeats images when images in huge count.

Answer (score 6):

NSURLConnection provides asynchronous downloading and is built into iOS.

Comment: Is this a better approach than `SDWebImage` as in does it have cache support ?

Comment: it stores the data into the memory. depends how you deal with the data.

Comment: Don't mind but suggesting alternate solution which requires again rebuilding efforts is not proper way to answer the questions. Now place yourself on his place and think if you need to rebuild all your stuff what you will do ? We should look at crash log and help him from there

Comment: He asked for other libraries he could use... and hasn't posted a crash log.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the bug that you describe may occur because when you "go back" release some objects that can be delegates of connections that are still running. For avoid crashes, you should cancel the connections before release or dealloc any object that could be a delegate of a running connection.

Another alternative for image async download is http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/  .

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is no good alternative anymore. Back in the days when the built in classes were too weak, it was nice to use, but now that NSURLConnection has grown up _and_ development for ASIHTTPRequest has been stopped, its not the best way to go anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I personally use the built in Grand Central Dispatch feature in iOS to download images from the server asynchronously.

Below is a code I used to fetch photos from Flickr in one of my apps.

In your image/photo class, have a function that is something like this:

```
- (void)processImageDataWithBlock:(void (^)(NSData *imageData))processImage
{
NSString *url = self.imageURL;
dispatch_queue_t callerQueue = dispatch_get_current_queue();
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Photo Downloader", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    NSData *imageData = *insert code that fetches photo from server*;
    dispatch_async(callerQueue, ^{
        processImage(imageData);
    });
});
dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
}
```

In your Photo View Controller, you can call this function like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[spinner startAnimating];
[self.photo processImageDataWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData) {
    if (self.view.window) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        imageView.image = image;
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        scrollView.contentSize = image.size;
        [spinner stopAnimating];
    }
}];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//JImage.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface JImage : UIImageView {

    NSURLConnection *connection;

    NSMutableData* data;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *ai;
}

-(void)initWithImageAtURL:(NSURL*)url;  

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection *connection;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData* data;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *ai;

@end



//JImage.m

#import "JImage.h"

@implementation JImage
@synthesize ai,connection, data;

-(void)initWithImageAtURL:(NSURL*)url {


    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    [self setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];

    if (!ai){

        [self setAi:[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]   initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge]]; 

        [ai startAnimating];

        [ai setFrame:CGRectMake(27.5, 27.5, 20, 20)];

        [ai setColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        [self addSubview:ai];
    }
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60];

    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];    
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)incrementalData {

if (data==nil) data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:5000];

[data appendData:incrementalData];

NSNumber *resourceLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[data length]];

NSLog(@"resourceData length: %d", [resourceLength intValue]);

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    NSLog(@"Connection error...");

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    [ai removeFromSuperview];

}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection 
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    [self setImage:[UIImage imageWithData: data]];

    [ai removeFromSuperview];   
}
@end



//Include the definition in your class where you want to use the image
-(UIImageView*)downloadImage:(NSURL*)url:(CGRect)frame {

JImage *photoImage=[[JImage alloc] init]; 

    photoImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 

   [photoImage setFrame:frame];

   [photoImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill]; 

    [photoImage initWithImageAtURL:url];

    return photoImage;
}


//How to call the class

UIImageView *imagV=[self downloadImage:url :rect]; 

//you can call the downloadImage function in looping statement and subview the returned  imageview. 
//it will help you in lazy loading of images.


//Hope this will help
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [EGOImageLoading](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading) by enormego for caching images.
It Works just like UIImageView and lets you download images from HTTP asynchronously and also its easy to integrate

Comment: Does it use any private APIs ?

Comment: No, it doesn't use any private APIs

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old thread but recently i had a lot of random crashes with SDWebImage, so i had to implement my own lazy loading and caching mechanism. It works pretty well, i just haven't tested it in heavy load cases. So here is the .h and .m files followed by the way i use it :

```
//  UIImageView+CustomCache.h
@interface UIImageView(CustomCache)

-(void)startAsyncDownload:(UIImage*)placeHolderImage imageUrlString:(NSString*)imageUrlString;
@end


//  UIImageView+CustomCache.m

#import "UIImageView+CustomCache.h"

@implementation UIImageView(CustomCache)

-(void)startAsyncDownload:(UIImage*)placeHolderImage imageUrlString:(NSString*)imageUrlString{
    self.image = placeHolderImage;
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                              [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString]] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionHandler){
        @autoreleasepool {
            if (connectionHandler != nil) {
                NSLog(@"error in downloading description %@",connectionHandler.localizedDescription);
            } else {
                ImagesCacheHandler *ref = [ImagesCacheHandler new];
                UIImage *imageFromData = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                if (imageFromData != NULL && imageFromData != nil && data.length > 0) {
                    self.image = imageFromData;
//custom store to sqlite
                    [ref archiveImage:imageUrlString imageData:data moc:[ref fetchContext]];
                }
            }
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

And in my table view i use (i import of course UIImageView+CustomCache.h)

```
UIImageView *imageViewToLazyLoad = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
[imageViewToLazyLoad startAsyncDownload:[UIImage imageNamed@"palce_Holder_Image_name"] imageUrlString:imageUrl];
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer using NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest and putting a GCD wrapper around it.  Keeps everything neat and tidy.