# Getting an image from a remote server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

In my iPhone app I have to show the preview of the thumbnail image. That preview image actually we will get from remote server. Before loading that big image on screen I have to show preloading view but actually this preloading view is not appearing on the screen.

The code I used is:

```
zoomview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
imageloadview.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5];
[self.view addSubview:imageloadview];
[activity startAnimating];
[self loadimageview];
```

Here instead of loading the zoom view on screen this loading view method is executing but I want to display preloading view before getting the big image from the server.

```
-(void)loadimageview
{
    imageloader.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@""];

    [self loadimage];
}

-(void)loadimage
{
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[picfullarray objectAtIndex:0]]];

    if([data length]==0)
    {
        NSLog(@"data");
    } 
    else
    {
        UIImage *image1=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
        imageloader.image=image1;

        [activity stopAnimating];
        [loadlabel1 setText:@""];
    }
}
```

How do I show preloaded view on iPhone screen before getting the big image from the server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763979/download-image-asynchronously/9766123#9766123 maybe asynchronously image downloading may help you..

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the image asynchronously with [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).

Make the class implement `NSURLRequestDelegate` protocol. In the function `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` of `NSURLRequestDelegate`, add the code to update the view when the loading is completed.

```
// You must declare NSMutableData somewhere to write received data in delegate method
// - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
// I assume the instance of NSMutableData is named data

// If you want to load multiple images, it is a bit tricky, but doable.
// I'll post the code if that is what you need.

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *) connection {
    // You may want to declare a instance member to store the image (UIImage*), so that you can restore the view if the view is unloaded due to memory warning.
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];


    data = nil; // Important. You should clean the data, or it will take up space.
    // You may want to check whether image != nil, since the incoming data may not be image
    [self displayImage: image];
}

- (void) displayImage: (UIImage*) aImage {
    imageloader.image = aImage;
    // Depending on how UIImageView is initialized, you may need to call sizeToFit.
    // Or set the frame accordingly

    [activity stopAnimating];
    [loadlabel1 setText: @""];
}
```

Comment: HI Thank you so much for your reply . can you please mention this elabarately . if it possible by using the code which i mentioned in above post.Thanking you.

Comment: The code example is in the link. I will only add a few more things that are not in the link so that it is clearer what you should do.

Comment: HI thanks , i need to mention one more condition that is actually i have 4 small image in those when ever the user click on the one image that preview we have to show in imageview that time which approach we have to follow.

Comment: Can you ask a new question? Actually, that is a problem that I also want to know the answer.

Comment: And one more question is i want to create 10 buttons programmatically without taking 10 button objects i would like to create those objects by using for loop like that logic and i would like to change their positions in potrait and landscape mode.how can we do this try to provide a code for this if it possible.

Comment: Would you please not asking the next question in the comment? You can totally start a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) framework. It already has async image loading capability, and it's super easy to use.

```
[imageView.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

You don't have to worry about messing with `NSURLConnection`, maintaining `NSData`, etc..

Answer (score 0):

There is also AFNetworking which has a way to do this easily.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking

Check out the "Download and Display Images" section.