# Slow loading of image from server iOS

Tags: iphone

I have tableview and rotary cover flow ,I'm showing image from server,but my app takes more time for loading the image.i doing JSON parsing for getting image.

Help me how can I do fast loading of image from server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: more time compared with what?

Comment: Check your network connectivity ..

Comment: Thanks for your response,more time in the sense showing the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should make the Asynchronous Call for downloading these Images.
On downloading the images for each row asynchronously  UI would be more responsive.

Here is Apple Already given the Sample Code for the Same..

[Here it is...!!!](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Here Are SOme more links which demonstrates the same Task.

[Here you go.](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView#readme)

[Here is Another Link for the Same.](http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/)

**EDIT:Here is a bit similar thread** 
[Here it is..!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763979/download-image-asynchronously)

I hope it may help you.