# how to download multiple images asyncronously

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download image asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763979/download-image-asynchronously)

I would like to download multiple images asynchronously. I have array of 10 images and I want to show these images in 10 `uiimageview`, I am doing like this but it show only one image

```
- (void)loadImage {
  NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[myarray objectatindex:0]]];
  UIImage* image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData] autorelease];
  [imageData release];
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayImage:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:NO];
}

The final method we need to create takes in the image to display and sets it on our image view.

- (void)displayImage:(UIImage *)image {
  [imageView setImage:image]; //UIImageView
}
```

So kindly tell me how I can show multiple images on different without creating 10 different methods.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `initWithContentsOfURL` method of `NSData`, which is synchronous.

You may want to consider the UIImageView+AFNetworking category that you can find [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/AFNetworking), that adds to `UIImageView` the ability to retrieve its content asynchronously.

As suggested in the comments you can also look at [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), which does basically the same.

Comment: yes this could be best way, as a alternative you can use SDWebImage that you can find https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: how do i will use that class

Comment: i include that sdwebimage file but i am getting lot of errors in this file like use of undeclare identifier _manager

Answer (score 0):

Just put those classes into your project and you have to import some classes thats all.
For sdwebimage you will get a method for uiimageview that is like "loadimagefrom url: withplaceholderimage" just check once I can't remember the method name.

Comment: i include that sdwebimage file but i am getting lot of errors in this file like use of undeclare identifier _manager

Comment: You have to include that whole library of sdwebimage