# Asynchronous image loading in UITableViewCell memory issue

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uitableview, uiimageview

In my iPhone application I have a tableview with custom imageview and loading images from remote location using AsyncImageView class. It works nicely, but one issue is, if I scroll the table, cells will be dequeued and it again trying to get the images from server. So, the method for loading image from AsyncImageView class is calling again and again hence increases the memory allocation, and eventually the app crashes.

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier {

    CGRect CellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 40);

    CGRect userImageFrame = CGRectMake(5, 7, 36, 36);

    UIImageView *userImage;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    [cell setFrame:CellFrame];

    userImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    userImage.frame = userImageFrame;
    userImage.tag = 3;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:userImage];
    [userImage release];

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
        cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];
    else
        [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:cell.imageView];

    UIImageView *userImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:3];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    NSString *url = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%@", CommonImageURL,[AllUsersProfileImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSURL *imageUrl =  [NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAppendingFormat:@"?%i", rand()]];
    [url release];

    userImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultPerson.png"];
    userImage.imageURL = imageUrl;
    return cell;
}
```

Is there any possible way to fix the issue? Please help.

Comment: Please let me know if anyone needs more information about the issue or code.

Comment: Are you looking for memory leaks search guide or for a better solution of images loading ?

Comment: I used EGOImageView and now AsyncImageView. Functionality wise both are good. But the issue is with memory allocation. I just want to avoid the increasing memory allocation issue.

Comment: Did you perform the leaks check ? If so, you'll probably need to get some disk caching to minimize the memory usage, also consider resizing   (downscaling) loaded images if they are not going to be reused, it could save some memory and make performance better as well.

Comment: I couldn't find leak issue, but it was increasing allocations. Will try by resizing the image. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution will be caching the image that is already downloaded and displaying it from there.

You need to write code for that, or there are some   libraries which provide such feature:

1. [HJCache](https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache)
2. [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: It's really important to make sure that the `cell` for the particular `indexPath` is still on screen and not reused for another `indexPath` before updating the imageview. Many of these async image downloaders don't do that, but just blithely update the imageview. A good implementation should allow a `completion` block (or delegate) where we can confirm that the `indexPath` is still visible before updating. Do any of these do that? This such a basic issue that surely some libraries must handle this gracefully. Which libraries handle this best?

Comment: Thank you for the references, now I am using SDWebImage. But got some error like Apple Mach-O Linker Error for some classes.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for the valuable comment, I used HJCashe before, It handles the issue, and a very good library

Comment: I had to add ImageIO framework, to get it working, now no errors :)

Answer (score 1):

The popular [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com) library also includes a UIImageView category to load images from the web which is often overlooked. I found it to be quite efficient with respect to memory usage and easy to use.

http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html

Answer (score 0):

I came across same trouble of memory leaks loading multiple images from server. My application needed fresh images response every time (functionality factor)

   I was using NSURLConnection using asynch requests. I tried with

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:0];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache]; // in DidFinishLoading & didFailWithError

receivedData=nil;  // at didReceiveResponse
receivedData=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

but nothing really helped , until I removed my cell
 `[cell removeFromSuperview];`  in cellForRowAtIndexPath and initialized it again FOR **every new** NSURL request (additional if condition on cellForRowAtIndexPath but REALLY that payed off).

Probably the UIImageViews were never removed and new images n data were added constantly as fetched by responses. Removing old UITableViewCell for a new NSURLRequest worked in my case.
   Hope this helps someone like me lost in cleaning NSURLCache and still memory beefing up.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a custom solution here
[Download image asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763979/download-image-asynchronously/22195250#22195250) .

I think it works ok and requires very little code.